# How to host PowerShell console in MMC?

Tags: powershell, administration, mmc

I am looking to find a way to host PowerShell console inside MMC. I have  customized MMC console which manages everything I need. I am learning PowerShell. So hosting it inside MC would be convenient (like hosting remote desktops). I have found *nothing* via Google on the subject. Please help.

MMC v3. Powershell v5. OSes: windows7-10, servers: 2008R2-2012R2.